# java selenium use variables in pattern matcher

Tags: java, selenium

I need help. This is the code I have now:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dateBirth);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(dateBirth.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
}
```

dateBirth date its = 3/11/11 from excel
result of this code is

```
 3
 11
 11
```

I want to take this 3 numbers, after matcher, and put to its own variable each.
But I don't know how. It need to be done to find date, mouth and year in drop down menu.

Comment: Why not just split on `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best:

```
LocalDate localDate =
    // Rearrange the date pattern to whatever you need, it's not clear.
    LocalDate.parse(dateBirth, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/y");
int year = localDate.getYear(); // May need to add 2000, if that's what you intend.
int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
int day = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
```

Alternative:

```
String[] parts = dateBirth.split("/");
int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
```

Comment: error ext '3/11/11' could not be parsed at index 0 =(